# Data not updated in secondary node of Mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I have created a Mongodb (v5.0.12) replica set with 2 nodes: 1 primary & 1 secondary.

The database syncing between the two nodes was working fine until today. I have some data which was wrote to primary node but not replicated to secondary node. Since the reads were being returned from secondary node, it did not return the updated data.

What can be the possible cause of such scenario ?

Comment: The secondary could be delayed by a few seconds, depending on your `writeConcern`

Comment: Take a look at [Write Concern for Replica Sets](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/#write-concern-for-replica-sets)

Comment: "_I have created a Mongodb (v5.0.12) replica set with 2 nodes: 1 primary & 1 secondary._" - it was the first mistake. Add at least an arbiter. "_Since the reads were being returned from secondary node_" - it was the second. Don't read from the secondaries if you are not happy with eventual consistency

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit could it be possible that it never updates value on secondary unless I delete the document from primary & add new one on the same ?

Comment: Command `db.getReplicationInfo()` should show the times when secondary was updated. Hava a look at it